# Date format Issue LocalDate to JqueryUi DatePicker

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, date, jquery-ui

I have a spring boot application that is sending an entity to the browser with a LocalDate field, the form field that receives this value in the browser is a jquery ui datepicker, I have added js code to format it to the same format but for some reason when I send today's date (June 5th 2020) it displays as MM/dd/yyyy even tough the value in the html source code seems to be correct. Any idea how to fix the display on the jquery ui datepicker?

Entity date field

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Column(name = "data",columnDefinition = "DATE")
private LocalDate data;
```

Controller  code piece

```
LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.now();
//this is the entity being sent to browser
Expense myExpense = new Expense();
myExpense.setData(myDate);
model.addAttribute("expense",myExpense);
```

Java script for datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $("#data").datepicker();
        $("#data").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" ).val();

});
```

In the link is a picture of the date displayed incorrectly as MM/dd/yyyy for (June 5th 2020) as if it was (May 6th 2020)

[image]

Html data source

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="data" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Data</label> 
                         <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-info" id="data" required name="data" value="05/06/2020"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Try commenting-out the first `$("#data").datepicker();`, worked for me without that.

Comment: yes that does work, but then the field becomes just a regular text field in which the user can enter anything, and has no date helper, Ive tried using the html 5 date field, but couldnt control the date format so thats why I went for the jquery ui datepicker, but it seems Im facing the same problem with it

Comment: To that, you can make the input field readonly, but then you have to offer something to clear. The datepicker does not have a way to do so, other than choosing another date.